# C++ Помогите пожалуйста дописать программу

Tags: c++

Даны натуральное число п, действительные числа а1 ..., an. В последовательности а1 ..., an определить число соседств двух чисел одного знака, причем модуль первого числа должен быть меньше модуля второго числа.

```
#include "iostream" 
#include "clocale" 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    int n, a, b, koll;
    cout << ("Введите количество элементов n=");
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "a" << i << " ";
        cin >> a;
        cout << "b" << i << " ";
        cin >> b;
        if (i > 0) 
        {
            if (a * b < 0)
                koll++;
        }
        b = a;
    }
    cout << "Ответ = " << koll << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы решаете не то, что задали. Вводите больше чисел, проверяете условие "разного знака", не проверяете все пары чисел, не сравниваете модули.

```
int main() {
    int n;
    cout << ("Введите количество элементов n=");
    cin >> n;
    int a, b, count = 0;
    cout << "a[1] = ";
    cin >> a;

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "a[" << i + 1 << "] = ";
        cin >> b;

        if (((a > 0 && b > 0) || (a < 0 && b < 0))
                && (abs(a) < abs(b))) count++;

        a = b;
        }

    cout << "Ответ = " << count << endl;
    }
```

Неизвестно толлько, как правильно обрабатывать 0 - в условии ничего об этом нет.

Comment: Думаю лучше сравеить так:  if ((a > 0 && b > а) || (a < 0 && b < а)) ++count;

Comment: @ARHovsepyan А как же условие **причем модуль первого числа должен быть меньше модуля второго числа**?

Comment: если число положительное и следующее число больше этого числа, то  второе тоже положительное и модуль первого меньше модулья второго, согласны? Теперь,  если число отрицательное, то  если следующее меньше, значит оно тоже отрицательное, и по модулью первое меньше второго. Что то не так?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Логично...

Answer (score 0):

функция, решает и возвращает ответ:

```
size_t sol(const int* arr, const size_t n)
{
    size_t count{};
    for (size_t i = 1; i < n; ++i)
    {
        int a = arr[i - 1], b = arr[i];
        count += ((a >= 0 && b > a) || (a < 0 && b < a));
    }
    return count;
}
```